# Is there an equivalent to an Android Handler in the WinRT API?

Tags: multithreading, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Android provides a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class that runs tasks (of type [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Message`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)) serially on a single thread. I am trying to reproduce this exact behavior in a Windows Store App and the only classes I see are [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpool.aspx) and [`ThreadPoolTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer.aspx) which I believe provides access to a pool of background threads, but what I want is access to a single background thread.

If it isn't possible with the WinRT API what about with [the allowed Win32 API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx#threads_and_synchronization)?

The reason for all this trouble is that I have an old C++ library that is only safe to run on a single thread but I don't want to run it on the UI thread since it could block it. Often times I'd like to queue up a bunch of tasks to have the library execute. `Handler` in Android was perfect for this.

Comment: Here's a crazy idea I just had. What if I use the ThreadPool to start a task. That task will be running on one of the background threads in the pool. In that task I will put loop that runs forever (or at least until I explicitly end it). Then I can send my individual work tasks to be processed in the loop so only one is processed at a time. I'm off to try that unless someone has a better answer.

Comment: Problem with my crazy idea is now I need a thread-safe queue...

Comment: For the thread safe collection, try [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Comment: I was planning on writing this in C++/CX which means I would need a WinRT or C++ class. BlockingCollection is a .NET class.

Comment: It's also available in win-rt (the little green hand-bag says so)

Comment: I believe the green hand-bag means you can use it for Windows Store Apps that are written in C#.

Comment: You are correct there. I guess I just assumed it would also be available in c++/cx. Honestly I dont know if that is true or not.

Comment: Just confirmed what you already knew - it's only for c#/vb. Sorry to mislead you.

Comment: And you don't know in advance all the tasks you'll have to run?

Comment: I don't know in advance, it all depends on what the user does.

Comment: I have another idea, create a class that contains a queue and runs a single task at a time, when the currently running task finishes it runs the next task if there is one. Each individual task will run on a thread randomly chosen by the ThreadPool but the class ensures only one runs at a time so it doesn't matter. The Queue itself won't be thread-safe so it will need to be invoked from UI thread only, that could be solved separately by using locks I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the answer is no, WinRT does not have a Handler class or an obvious substitute.

However, I was able to write a WinRT class in C++/CX that replicates most of the behavior. I did this using the `Concurrency::concurrent_queue` class and the `Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool` class. Basically my WinRT Handler class exposes a method that accepts a `Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler` and a `Windows::Foundation::AsyncActionCompletedHandler` and uses a queue to run the submitted work items one at a time using the `ThreadPool`. When a work item is complete the `AsyncActionCompletedHandler` is called. The exposed method returns a custom cancel token object that allows the user to cancel the work. If no tasks are running it starts one immediately, otherwise it adds it to the queue, when one finishes it looks at the queue and starts the next one if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my naive implementation of the Android handler (at least I've tried my best):

```
public class Handler
{
    private static readonly BlockingCollection<Action> queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    static void Loop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action task = queue.Take();

            if (task == null) break;

            task();
        }
    }

    static Handler()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Loop);
        thread.Name = "Handler";
        thread.Start();
    }

    public static void Post(Action task)
    {
        queue.Add(task);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Launching tasks");

        Handler.Post(() => { Console.WriteLine("Running task 1..."); Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine("Task 1 done."); });
        Handler.Post(() => { Console.WriteLine("Running task 2..."); Thread.Sleep(3000); Console.WriteLine("Task 2 done."); });
        Handler.Post(() => { Console.WriteLine("Running task 3..."); Thread.Sleep(2000); Console.WriteLine("Task 3 done."); });
        Handler.Post(null);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting end of tasks");
    }
}
```

Does it fit your needs?

Comment: I'm looking for something in C++ or C++/CX since my library is C++.

Comment: OK, so you need to find the equivalent of two things: BlockingCollection and lambdas. Sorry but can't help for that. :( If you don't know either open a new question. (would be interested to know too :))